# Transpose using a key MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot-table

I have a need to transpose the table, but very specifically on a key ID, essentially I need a GROUP BY that makes new columns based on columns existing within a table already.  I have made a few examples below for clarification.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID,  Dates,                State
'1','2015-10-01 21:20:40','Arrived'
'1','2015-10-01 21:21:40','Pulling In'
'1','2015-10-01 21:31:40','Unloading'
'1','2015-10-01 21:50:48','Finished Unloading'
'1','2015-10-01 21:55:48','Pulled Out'
'2','2015-10-01 19:22:03','Arrived'
'2','2015-10-01 19:23:03','Pulling In'
'2','2015-10-01 19:33:03','Unloading'
'2','2015-10-01 19:47:41','Finished Unloading'
'2','2015-10-01 19:52:41','Pulled Out'
'3','2015-10-01 12:32:27','Arrived'
'3','2015-10-01 12:33:27','Pulling In'
'3','2015-10-01 12:43:27','Unloading'
'3','2015-10-01 13:03:08','Finished Unloading'
'3','2015-10-01 13:08:08','Pulled Out'
```

I would like to transpose via the ID column, making:

```
ID, Arrived_date, Pulling_In_Date, Unloading_Date, Finished_Unloading_Date, Pulled_Out_Date
'1','2015-10-01 21:20:40','2015-10-01 21:21:40','2015-10-01 21:31:40', '2015-10-01 21:50:48','2015-10-01 21:50:48' 
'2','2015-10-01 19:22:03','2015-10-01 19:23:03','2015-10-01 19:33:03', '2015-10-01 19:33:03', '2015-10-01 19:52:41'
'3','2015-10-01 12:32:27','2015-10-01 12:33:27','2015-10-01 12:43:27', '2015-10-01 13:03:08','2015-10-01 13:08:08'
```

I have this so far

```
SELECT ID, 
(case when State = "Arrived" then Dates end) as Arrived_Date,
(case when State = "Pulling In" then Dates end) as Pulled_In_Date,
(case when State = "Unloading" then Dates end) as Unloading_Date,
(case when State = "Finished Unloading" then Dates end) as 
Finished_Unloading_Date,
(case when State = "Pulled Out" then Dates end) as Pulled_Out_Date
FROM IDDateState;`
```

This this gets:

```
ID, Arrived_date, Pulling_In_Date, Unloading_Date, Finished_Unloading_Date, Pulled_Out_Date
'1','2015-10-01 21:20:40',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'1',NULL,'2015-10-01 21:21:40',NULL,NULL,NULL
'1',NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 21:31:40',NULL,NULL
'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 21:50:48',NULL
'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 21:55:48'
'2','2015-10-01 19:22:03',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'2',NULL,'2015-10-01 19:23:03',NULL,NULL,NULL
'2',NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 19:33:03',NULL,NULL
'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 19:47:41',NULL
'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 19:52:41'
'3','2015-10-01 12:32:27',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'3',NULL,'2015-10-01 12:33:27',NULL,NULL,NULL
'3',NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 12:43:27',NULL,NULL
'3',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 13:03:08',NULL
'3',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-10-01 13:08:08'
```

I want to somehow group by the TID, but I get:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of select list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'IDDateState.State' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have been searching for the solution for a few hours now and would like help, Please let me know if there is a better way or if there is something I'm doing wrong.  Thank you

Comment: This is called "pivot" in databases, not "transpose". If you knew that you probably could have found the solution yourself.

Comment: When you edit, continue from a previous edit, so the formatting improvements are preserved

Comment: @Barmar - 4th pivot question today...we need a community wiki answer that we can point these questions at.

Comment: @Twelfth Only 4th? I thought I already closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I did not know it was called a Pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an aggregate (like `max` or `min`) so the database knows how to choose one value from among the group. For example:

```
SELECT  ID
,       max(case when State = "Arrived" then Dates end) as Arrived_Date
,       max(case when State = "Pulling In" then Dates end) as Pulled_In_Date
,       max(case when State = "Unloading" then Dates end) as Unloading_Date
,       max(case when State = "Finished Unloading" then Dates end)
            as Finished_Unloading_Date
,       max(case when State = "Pulled Out" then Dates end) as Pulled_Out_Date
FROM    IDDateState
GROUP BY
        ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responce.
Trying the above code you presented I get:
'1','20151001212040','2015-10-01 21:21:40','2015-10-01 21:31:40','2015-10-01 21:50:48','2015-10-01 21:55:48'
'2','20151001192203','2015-10-01 19:23:03','2015-10-01 19:33:03','2015-10-01 19:47:41','2015-10-01 19:52:41'
'3','20151001123227','2015-10-01 12:33:27','2015-10-01 12:43:27','2015-10-01 13:03:08','2015-10-01 13:08:08'

Comment: The first date comes out as a string loosing the -'s I'm not sure why but I'll try looking into it